# Sony Xperia Z1 Compatibility

Tags: sync

I am a brand new Ubuntu User. Is a Xperia Z1 Compact Smartphone compatible to Ubuntu? I am using my Smartphone as MP3 Player and Camera and i want to sync it.

Answer (score 1):

[Syncthing](https://syncthing.net/) is available on Android and Ubuntu. I use it to sync some folders like music from my main computer to some devices without connecting them via cable.

Answer (score 0):

Being an Android user (before Galaxy S5, LG G3 and currently Nexus 6) as far as I know that you can connect/pair all of Android devices without any problem.

Modern Android devices (such as Xperia Z1) support [MTP (Media Transfer Protocol)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol) and [PTP (Picture Transfer Protocol)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picture_Transfer_Protocol). You can select which protocol you want to use when you connect your phone via USB cable (shown below, image reference [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/192732/android-usb-connections-explained-mtp-ptp-and-usb-mass-storage/)).

[image: Selecting different connection methods]

You phone will also show the current connection mode in notification area (shown below, image reference [here](http://www.itjungles.com/samsung-galaxy-note-2-how-to-change-the-usb-connection-as-a-media-device-mode.html)).

[image]